# Calling external service inside Orika custom mapper

Tags: mapping, orika

Let's admit I want to map an object **A** to an object **B** with Orika.
One field of the object **B** is constructed by a call to an external webservice with a parameter I have in object **A**.

Is it a good practice to create an Orika custom-mapper which uses a service that makes a call to an external service, or should I separate this behaviour in an external class ?

```
          External service
                ^
                |
[A]-----> Custom Mapper ------> [B]
```

Answer (score 0):

Custom mappers in Orika can be regular Spring Beans there is already a lot of example on how to create Spring based Orika mapper

Take a look of this example:

https://github.com/dlizarra/orika-spring-integration

**UPDATE**
Yes absolutely.

Comment: I'm not looking to see if it is possible to integrate Orika in Spring (already done), but more if it is a good practice to have in a custom mapper a connection to an external service which can take time and fail. I'm editing my title since it is not clear.